# Alamofire 5 send array of dictionaries

Tags: swift, alamofire

I tried to send an array of dictionaries but the server receive another object

ejm

```
let param: [String: Any] = [
    "info1": "test",
    "info2": [
        [
            "material_id": 1,
            "qty": 10
        ],
        [
            "material_id": 2,
            "qty": 5
        ]
    ]
]

 let request = AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params)
        request.responseJSON { response in
            guard response.error == nil else {
                print(response.error)
                return
            }
print(response.value)
        }
```

in my server when I print $_POST["info2"] the result is:

```
▿ value : 4 elements
        ▿ 0 : 1 element
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : material_id
            - value : 1
        ▿ 1 : 1 element
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : qty
            - value : 10
        ▿ 2 : 1 element
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : material_id
            - value : 2
        ▿ 3 : 1 element
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : qty
            - value : 5
```

im trying to encode the request but alamofire doesnt allow any to encode

Comment: You can try `encoding: JSONEncoding.default` on your request function - does this solve the encoding question?

Comment: hi @HarryJ doesnt work i receive an error, bc any isn't encodable